# Will this static assert work correctlly?

Tags: c++, static-assert

I saw recently following code:

```
#define MY_ASSERT_CONCAT_(a, b) a##b
#define MY_ASSERT_CONCAT(a, b) MY_ASSERT_CONCAT_(a, b)
#define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(e,msg) enum { MY_ASSERT_CONCAT(assert_line_,__LINE__) = 1/int(!!(e)) }
```

Will it work as expected (BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT-like) ?

Comment: You could make your question more precise by telling us how you are trying to use it. Like this, the `msg` parameter is not used, which is strange.

Comment: What's wrong with `static_assert` ?

Comment: It doesn't work in MSVC 2010, the compiler can't detect that `1/int(!!(e))` is a constant when I pass 0 as `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work for you?

```
#define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(e,msg) \
{   \
        int MY_ASSERT_CONCAT(assert_line_,__LINE__)[!!e]; \
        MY_ASSERT_CONCAT(assert_line_,__LINE__); \
}
```

It is trying to declare an array of size 1 or 0, depending on expression. It would work only on VC, since GCC allows zero sized arrays(by default). Second usage is just *using the variable*, so that compiler wont emit "unused variable" warning.
Note that there are no spaces after backslash (`\`), and it works on VC. Either change it to single line macro, or use appropriate alternative in you compiler.

I recommend using `static_assert` instead, which will produce elegant error message (and just one error message!).